# Optimizing code with a potential polynomial Big O run time

Tags: python, recursion, big-o

In one of my interviews, I was asked a question to determine if a given string is a valid English phrase. The string in question, is a collection of alphanumeric characters with no delimiters, including spaces. The assumption was there was a 'dictionary' somewhere that contained all valid words, and could be used as a reference to determine if a word was valid or not. This 'dictionary' could be implemented using any appropriate mechanism/data structure.

My solution was done using Python and involved recursion. Here is what I proposed:

```
def isphrase(string, words):
"""
Determine if a given string (containing no spaces or delimiters) is a 
valid English phrase
:param string: String to be checked
:param words: Collection of English words as an iterable or in a file
:return:  True, if it is a phrase
         False, otherwise
"""

if len(string) == 0:
    return True

if string in words:
    return True

for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[:i+1] in words and isphrase(string[i+1:], words):
        return True

return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = {"i", "am", "here", "there", "you", "were"}
    print(isphrase("thereyou", words))
```

The solution was accepted as a viable solution, but while working out the time complexity, this comes out to a O(n!) in a worse case situation. Is there a way to make this closer to a O(nlogn) or something like it? Should I adopt a divide-and-conquer philosophy instead of this approach?

P.S: I used a set to hold the collection of words. Please do feel free to provide your suggestions/comments on this as well.

Comment: FYI, this problem looks like https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/. You can solve it with dynamic programming.

Comment: This is better suited for [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic programming solution:

```
def isphrase(s, word_dict):
    size = len(s)

    if size == 0:
        return False

    dp = [False]*(size+1)
    dp[0] = True
    for i in range(size):
        if dp[i]:
            for j in range(i, size):
                if s[i:j+1] in word_dict:
                    dp[j+1] = True
    return dp[j+1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = {"i", "am", "here", "there", "you", "were"}
    print(isphrase("thereyou", words))
```

You can keep subwords in a list so you don't constantly recalculate them. A faster solution would be to use a top-down dynamic programming approach (left as an exercise to the reader) or anothe possibility is to use a trie instead.